# Column space and null space are equal for nilpotent $n \times n$ matrix with $n$ even and $\text{rank}(A)=n/2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

How can I prove

> Let $A$ be $n \times n$ with $n$ even, $\text{rank}(A)=n/2$ and $A^2=0$. Then $C(A) = N(A)$.

I thought about proving it by showing that each set is contained in the other. Indeed the one direction is easy.

Let $\mathbf{b} \in C(A)$ then $\mathbf{b}=A\mathbf{x}$ for some $\mathbf{x} \in \Bbb R^n$. Because $A^2=\mathbf{0}$ we get $A\mathbf{b} = AA\mathbf{x} = A^2\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ and so $\mathbf{b} \in N(A)$.

But what about the other direction?

Let $\mathbf{b} \in N(A)$ then $A\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{0}$. How do I conclude that there exists $\mathbf{x} \in \Bbb R^n$ such that $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not look right, for instance take
$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\dim(C(A)) = 1$ and $\dim(N(A)) = 3$.

(The zero matrix would have also sufficed, but I thought that would have been too trivial an example.)

---

**PS** OP has already proved that if $A^{2} = 0$, then $C(A) \subseteq N(A)$. Now the usual [range-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) tells you that
$$
n = \dim(C(A)) + \dim(N(A)).
$$
Therefore $C(A) = N(A)$ iff their common dimension is $n/2$ iff $\dim(C(A))$, which is the rank of $A$, is $n/2$.